# Hexahedral mesh generation around two cylinders junction

Tags: numerical-methods, math-software, computational-geometry, finite-element-method, meshing

I need to design a mesh for Finite Element Method around the junction of two hollow cylinders.
Here is an example of mesh geometry: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0hVX.png.
I've found how to generate a mesh around one cylinder using cylindrical coordinates to arrange the mesh nodes (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjGiK.png), but can't find a way to adapt this approach to generate hexahedral cells in the area of cylinders junction.

What alternative approach could you recommend to do that?
What literature could help?
Is there any software that can help me to generate the desired mesh? Either freeware, or not. I mean specifically mesh generator as a separate tool.

Any advice and comment on the subject will be appreciated.

Comment: You can try TrueGrid software: http://truegrid.com/GalleryHome.html.